# What to do when distance function returns equal value for two classes in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, distance, weka, metrics

For classifying `object o`, if its distance function such as Manhattan distance gets the equal result for two classes A and B, what should I do? It means, `dist(A,o) = dist(B,o)`. And what do the well-known classifier tools such as Weka do in this situation?

Thank you so much! :)